# Moving an existing site to Mongo DB

Tags: 7, migrations, database

How hard is it to move a live site to mongoDB when its traffic hits high? Is it easy to built a Drupal site on it? How is the learning curve for a developer who is quite comfortable with Drupal7 and php.

Comment: See this nice article http://drupalconnect.com/blog/converting-existing-drupal-site-mongodb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're going to use the [mongoDB module](http://drupal.org/project/mongodb). This doesn't move the ENTIRE database over, just parts of it, like cache, blocks, watchdog, etc.

This works well because mongo, or any "document" oriented database is not great at relations. So you can move the data that is not very relational into mongoDB easily.

Mongo itself is cake. Easy to install, easy to understand. It's simply "JSON" data. If you don't know JSON, read up on it now. Already, many parts of Drupal's data are stored as JSON inside text fields in a regular SQL database such as MySQL.

I'd re-iterate that you probably don't want to move EVERYTHING over, like the nodes, taxonomy, etc. Those things are highly relational. Also, the mongoDB module doesn't support those for that reason.

Installation of the module is pretty straight forward and happens in settings.php. See the [mongo module readme file](http://drupalcode.org/project/mongodb.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt) for more info.

Comment: Will there be any serious changes you will have to do to your site? Or does the module automatically start using mongodb for your cache, block etc?

Comment: I've never used it, so I can't tell you for sure, but in theory it should work with ZERO problems on things like cache. They're simply rebuilt. Where data is more permanent, such as "Blocks", I'd assume you'd need to import the data into mongo somehow. The module might do this for you, I'm not sure. I think you'll probably just have to give it a go.

Comment: Sure. I will do that. I am going to work on a really huge media portal for a television channel with at least 50k hits per day. I believe I should think of this more seriously.

Comment: If you're looking for performance and your users are NOT authenticated then this should be pretty easy to acheive with Varnish. At least from the drupal side. You'll also want to make sure you have CDN for a media site. I'm sure you know this but I've run a few large drupal sites and the bottleneck was usually the CDN, not Drupal (for non-authenticated users, that is).

Answer (score 2):

Fields on a live site can be migrated with drush to mongodb as per chx's post here https://drupal.org/node/1653202